# vb.net XML (SVG) xlink:href=

Tags: xml, vb.net, svg

I am trying to make a .svg file using vb.net and I need to add a company logo.

I am using the following code to add the image element:

```
 'Add logo 
        .WriteStartElement("image")
        .WriteAttributeString("width", "100")
        .WriteAttributeString("height", "100")
        .WriteAttributeString("xlink", "href", "data:img/png;base64, string of company logo")
        .WriteAttributeString("x", "200")
        .WriteAttributeString("y", "200")
```

But I end up with this in my XML file:

```
<image width="100" height="100" p4:xlink="data:img/png;base64, string of company logo" />
```

But I want to end up with:

```
<image width="100" height="100" xlink:href="data:img/png;base64, string of company logo" />
```

What am I doing wrong? and what do I need to change in my code to get the required result in my .svg file?

Comment: I am a bit puzzled .. can't a resized version of the .png be used directly, instead of embedding it in a .svg file?

Comment: Seems like you have the parameters in the wrong order. Check the documentation and examples https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xkd34zdt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed my problem by changing this line:

```
 .WriteAttributeString("xlink", "href", "data:img/png;base64, string of company logo")
```

to this

```
 .WriteAttributeString("xlink", "href", Nothing, "data:img/png;base64, string of company logo")
```

not sure why this works and my earlier solution didn....

Answer (score 1):

1.First, you need to import namespace (change `namespace` to the one you need)

```
Imports <xmlns:xlink="mynamespace">
```

2.VB.NET has unique feature - XML Literals. You can embed values into elements and attributes easily:

```
Dim height = 100
Dim width = 100
Dim href = "data:img/png;base64, string of company logo"
Dim xml = <image width=<%= width %> height=<%= height %> xlink:href=<%= href %>/>
```

3.Call ToString() when you need string representation of your XML:

```
Dim xmlString = xml.ToString()
```

Comment: This gives me an error that a = is expected on the "dim xml ="  part and how do I write this to my XML file? because the last line Dim xmlString = xml.ToString() doesnt add anything tot the xml I think?

Comment: @Fyer-Zero I have corrected error. Now code works as expected!

Answer (score 0):

I was about to suggest [XML Literals](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/xml/xml-literals-overview) like in @JohnyL's answer, but might be easier to hard-code it:

```
Dim xml = "<image width=""100"" height=""100"" xlink:href=""data:img/png;base64," &  
                                                            stringOfCompanyLogo & """ />"
File.WriteAllText(filePath, xml)
```

Note that the `xlink:` namespace is deprecated in SVG 2
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/xlink:href

Comment: The xlink namespace may be deprecated in SVG but Safari doesn't yet support bare href, Firefox, Chrome and Edge do though.